# Is it possible to define a bottom class in a sublattice of Scala's type hierarchy?

Tags: scala, types

Say I have an abstract class `A`. Now I want to define a final class `ABot` such that for any class `B` that extends `A` (except `Nothing`), `ABot` is a subclass of `B`. It's just like `Nothing`, but with respect to the hierarchy where `A` is the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is **No**.

> A class will not be a subtype of X unless you explicitly extend X.

`scala.Nothing` is an exception because Scala compiler does the magic for you.

Comment: What if I require `ABot` to be the subclass of any class subtyping `A` *except* `Nothing`?

Answer (score 0):

If there are two classes `B` and `C`, which extend `A` but neither of them extends the other, you can't have a class (or a trait) which extends both.